# Master Detail and Roll up summary limits

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

**How many master detail relationships and lookup relationships can we create on an object? (For Latest Salesforce Release)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create up to [2 Master-Detail Fields on a single Object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=0) and with Winter '16, the default limit on roll-up summary fields per object has been [increased from 10 to 25](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqY2AAK).

Comment: what about '17 release ?

Comment: @SourabhCoolkarni As of and if you read the [release notes](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter17_release_notes.pdf), you'll find nothing has changed in relation to this. Limits are the same.